# Force java program to use GTK2

Tags: java, gtk, eclipse-rcp, gtk2

I am able to force eclipse to use gtk2 by inserting this to `eclipse.ini` file.

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

However, after exporting the product via Eclipse Product export wizard, `myApp.ini` file does not include this line snippet and I could not figure out how to force exported product to use gtk2. When I add same line to `myApp.ini` file, it does not work.

Initial content of myApp.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.0.v20180512-1130.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1000.v20190125-2016
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms512m
-Xmx2g
-Dmessaging.jms.brokerUrl=failover:(tcp://rasat-pardus:61616)
-Dlogback.configurationFile=${workspace_loc}/tr.gov.tubitak.uzay.yerist.gp.app.fragment/conf/logback-config.xml
-Dorg.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j
-Duser.timezone=UTC
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:NewRatio=3
```

I tried to insert the `launcher.GTK_version 2` to various lines, and none of them worked.

Is there any way to solve that?
Is there any other way to force gtk2?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You use Eclipse 4.11 or higher (`org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.1000.v20190125-2016` was built on January 25, 2019 which is after the release date of Eclipse 4.10), but [**GTK2 support was dropped in Eclipse 4.10**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/platform.php#gtk2-removal).

Comment: However my program runs as I expect when I run it from eclipse. My problem occurs when I create the product by exporting it. So if my eclipse version did not support GTK2, why I can successfully force it via eclipse run, but not in product?

Comment: Putting that entry in the eclipse.ini only changes Eclipse itself, it does not change what is used when you run your code from Eclipse.

Comment: Maybe the target platform contains different versions and in the launch configuration you are explicitly using older version. As Greg already said, it is irrelevant what is in the eclipse.ini of the IDE you are using. To be more specific, one would have to know the launch configuration and what is in the target platform.

Comment: If I use older version of eclipse, how would I convert my current target platform to that specific eclipse version? I know this is a different topic, but I do not know which keywords to search for in this problem's context.

Comment: @Sami In _Window > Preferences: Plug-in Development > Target Platform_ add a target platform with the location of that specific installed/unzipped Eclipse version and activate it. Alternatively, a [target platform can also be specified by a `.target` file](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html).